# Ec2 not properly reflecting github changes

Tags: python, django, github, amazon-ec2

I deployed my Django project to an ec2 server successfully but the code doesn't necessarily update properly. My first code pull worked successfully initially, but for some reason maybe depending on the browser, there's a 50/50 chance I'll have to refresh that page I updating to see the changes. Also, my second pull wasn't acknowledged at all. I added some  tag links and they just don't show up? What could be going on here?

Comment: Are you restarting the uwsgi or gunicorn processes after git pull? Template changes show up if no template cache is setup.  Python file changes require a server process restart

Comment: @MichaelLindsay at first I only ran sudo service nginx restart, then i tried sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
sudo systemctl status gunicorn then i restarted and I believe fixed the issue.

Comment: There are tools to automate both steps at once. Fabric/fab-classic are python based. a simple shell script could help also.